# Class static side 'typeof _Readable' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Readable'

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, types

I'm working on a bot for Discord using node/typescript. When I run the typescript compiler over my source code, I am getting this error:

```
node_modules/@types/readable-stream/index.d.ts(13,15): error TS2417: Class static side 'typeof _Readable' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Readable'.
  The types of 'Stream.Readable.Writable' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'typeof _Readable.Writable' is not assignable to type 'typeof import("stream").Writable'.
      Types of parameters 'options' and 'opts' are incompatible.
        Type 'import("stream").WritableOptions' is not assignable to type '_Readable.WritableOptions'.
          Type 'WritableOptions' is not assignable to type 'WritableStateOptions'.
            Types of property 'defaultEncoding' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'BufferEncoding'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! Shattered-Star@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Shattered-Star@1.0.0 tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've tried reinstalling `@types/node` since that seems to be the module where this is coming from, but that hasn't caused any changes. As far as I know, none of my source code is even making use of the `readable-streams` sub-module. In fact, removing it solves my problem - I just want to know what exactly happened. Here is my `tsconfig.json` in case I'm missing something there:

```
{

    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "built/",
        "moduleResolution": "Node"
    },
    "include": [
        "./bot/**/*"
    ]

}
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Hopefully I'm not the only person who's bumped into this situation. Thanks!

Comment: I just forgot to 'yarn', so I'm leaving this comment for every other idiot like me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I run into this issue lately.
This seems to be a typing incompatibility between the last version of `@types/readable-stream` (2.3.6) and your version of `node`.

*You can check in you yarn.lock / package-lock.json for the presence of this package in this version*

It seems that `@types/readable-stream@2.3.6` is `node >= 14`-compatible while `@types/readable-stream@2.3.5` is `node < 14`-compatible

There is how I had it fixed in my environment `node < 14`:

```
yarn add -D --exact @types/readable-stream@2.3.5
```

Or with npm:

```
npm i -D -E @types/readable-stream@2.3.5
```

*This overrides the `@types/readable-stream` package version and sets in explicitly to the `2.3.5` fixed version by adding `"@types/readable-stream": "2.3.5"` in your package.json devDependencies*

---

I guess (but I didn't test it) that I you run into this same issue and your `node` version is `>= 14`, you might have to do perform the same operation with the `2.3.6` version of `@types/readable-stream`

---

Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/44828

Comment: Thanks for the response. Oddly enough, doing the opposite seemed to solve the problem. I'm running `node v14.2.0` and `@types/readable-stream@2.3.5` without issue. I wonder if any changes between `node v14` and `node v14.2` would have cause some compatibility changes with `readable-streams`...

Comment: Worked for node v12.13.1

Comment: Seems that there is relation between specific node versions and readable-stream derfinitions. I had node **v12.16.1** and had `@types/readable-stream@2.3.5` as well as `@types/readable-stream@2.3.7` for another dependency in the lock file. I tried both without success and went to **@latest**, which turned out to be `@types/readable-stream@2.3.9` and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to `@types/readable-stream@2.3.7` on node version `v12.18.1` fixed this issue for me.